# Prefect Job Scheduling for specific date and time

Tags: scheduled-tasks, scheduling, job-scheduling, prefect

I want to schedule jobs in prefect for non-cron and intervals , I have some specific dates for which I want the flow to run, I saw that it is possible in prefect 1 using DateClocks but I do not see any example, can you provide me with one that includes time zone as well?
I want to use code to do this rather than the UI

I Haven't tried it it because I am new to this, I want to set up runs for specific dates, can you please give me an example where we can include timezone as well?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's very doable - the easiest way is to leverage `pendulum` and the `run_deployment` utility:

```py
import pendulum
from prefect.deployments import run_deployment

run_deployment(
    name="flow/deploy_name",
    scheduled_time=pendulum.datetime(2023, 4, 1, 20, 0, 0, 0, tz="Europe/Berlin"),
)
run_deployment(
    name="flow/deploy_name",
    scheduled_time=pendulum.datetime(2023, 4, 2, 20, 0, 0, 0, tz="Europe/Berlin"),
)
```

Comment: would I need to put the entire path of the flow I am registering in name if I use this method? and I just just add default_params after the deployments to give parameters for each flow right?

Comment: Can you also tell me how to set all the clock parts to have n dates but the time should be 8 pm EST?

Comment: The solution given above doesn't work with prefect one, Can anyone help me with prefect 1 solution?